# Javascript getbetween function multiple instances

Tags: javascript

```
function getBetween(content, start, end) {
    var r = content.split(start);
    if (1 in r) {
        var z = r[1].split(end);
        return z[0];
    }
    return '';
}
```

Hello, I have the following the function that I've written that can get a string between two strings

for example

```
var string = 'I am 30 years old';
var age = getBetween(string, 'I am ', ' years old');
```

Now, what if string had more occurrences to the age, for example if `string` was
`I am 30 years old
I am 20 years old
I am 50 years old`

Etc etc.. I was wondering if there was a way to get 30, 20, 50 and whatever other matches in an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
function getBetween(content, start, end) {
   var arr = [];
   content.replace(new RegExp(start + "(.+)" + end,"g"),function(m,g1){ arr.push(g1); return '';});
   return arr;
}

var output = getBetween('I am 30 years old I am 20 years old I am 50 years old', 'I am ', ' years old');
```

Output:

```
["30", "20", "50"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
function getBetween(content, start, end) {
    var result = [];
    var r = content.split(start);
    for (var i = 1; i < r.length; i++) {
        result.push(r[i].split(end)[0]);
    }
    return result;
}

var output = getBetween('I am 30 years old I am 20 years old I am 50 years old', 'I am ', ' years old');
```

Output:

```
["30", "20", "50"]
```

Comment: you don't mind if I copy your input and output right?